# Auto Smooth Shading of old file

Tags: shaders

I tried to use a .blend file that is 1 year old. I wanted to use the mesh to animate something, but I noticed I used EdgeSplit instead of auto-smoothing a year ago. Here is the problem, when I "remove doubles" and turn on auto-smooth nothing happens. Is the file corrupted, does Blender doesn't support older .blend files? Please help, I literally sat 3 hours here pressing random buttons like a monkey and nothing seems to work <3

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_kJOb3u2J0gX0VCWUU2aW02ckU

Comment: Auto-smooth? Also you can't remove doubles as there are none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently *Auto Smooth* wont work if you have custom split normals, if you want to use it you will have to remove any custom normals and loose it's data.

In the *Properties Window > Object Data (Mesh tab) > Geometry Data Panel > Clear Custom Split Normals Data* button and you should be able to use *Auto Smooth*

Otherwise just add an *Edge Split Modifier*

Comment: Omg thank you very very much <3. So, looks like whenever I use an EdgeSplit modifier, Blender makes these custom normals? <3

Comment: Not sure how they are created, I think it's not the Edge Split modifier, they are either created by hand or using the normal edit modifier, or created by some addons,  but I'm not sure