# Shading glitch in Blender

Tags: shaders, baking

I imported this model from Maya, though the mesh is still "Weird" in Maya. I'm unaware of the issue. The hand mesh I used has this shading problem, it also messes up the AO bake I try to do. Though I'm using smooth shading the flat shading shows the problem I suppose. How can I fix this?

[[image: Image of this]][[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aLmb.png)

Comment: Possibly related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52492/auto-smooth-shading-of-old-file/

Comment: As was imported  need to clear custom split normals that were likely added, otherwise auto-smooth.

Comment: Thank you @Timaroberts that fixed it! I'm happy that this annoying issue is fixed finally. Clearing custom split normals, is that something I should normally do when importing models?